# How do I select multiple controls(buttons) at a time c#

Tags: c#, controls, button

How do i select many buttons at a time on a flowlayoutpanel
c#

Comment: Probably on a Windows Form Application in Visual Studio.

Comment: This question needs to be more specific.

Comment: it means that on a flowlayoutpanel , i wanna select many buttons at a time

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about during design-time, just hold Ctrl while clicking each button...or click and drag the mouse to select the buttons you're interested in.

If you're talking about run-time...you can only click one button at a time.

Comment: even after creating one by one on runtime too?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're talking about the form designer:

- Draw a selection box around the controls you'd like to select
- Hold down ctrl + click or shift+click on the control you'd like to select in addition to your current control.
- To select all contorls you can use Ctrl + A and then then you can subtract from your selecting using ctrl + click or shift + click

Surprisingly there is an [MSDN page which describes the process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1bd4c7h8.aspx).

Comment: i've seen that page but i don't think it helps on a flowlayout panel

Answer (score 0):

Hold CTRL, and click on the buttons.

Comment: well actually im trying to implement this on a flowlayout panel and i wonder whether it's possible?

Comment: It is possible, I just tested it (WinForms).

Comment: but my program has this scenario which the buttons are not present right when you open it . well it has a tool which  creates a button  on runtime

Comment: Well, you cannot select multiple buttons at runtime.